# Failed to upgrade windows 7 from 32bit to 64bit

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-upgrade

there when I trying to upgrade my windows 7 from 32bit to 64bit i got this message

[image]

Please someboady help me how to fix this

This is my current windows that I used

[image: This is my current windows that I used][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlVRi.jpg)

Comment: Run the windows setup from within win 7 (using usb / mounting iso)

Comment: Windows cannot be upgraded from 32 to 64-bit. You need to wipe & start afresh.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU
[Intel Core2 Duo Processor E7500](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/36503/intel-core-2-duo-processor-e7500-3m-cache-2-93-ghz-1066-mhz-fsb.html)
is 64-bit, so Windows can be converted to 64-bit.

This is done by re-installing Windows 7, as 64-bit is not an upgrade to 32-bit,
but rather a different version.

- Backup all your data
- Create a boot media for Windows 7 64-bit
- Boot from this media
- Click "Install now" after you set up language and other preference
- Accept the license terms and click Next.
- If the system partition has enough free space,
  you may use it to clean install Windows 64-bit.
  Otherwise you may need to delete the partition and install to the Unallocated space.
- After installation, the folder `Windows.old` saves your previous Windows
  and gives you a chance to restore desktop and programs from it.